# Take a list on one sheet then find appropriate tab and copy contents to next available row in another sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, tabs

I have been wrestling with this for a day or so and am stumped.

Here is what I want to do:

I have a sheet with a complete list of the tab names in column A. Call this Total Tabs.

I have another sheet called "Reps No Longer Here". This is the target sheet where the contents of the individual tabs in the list are to be copied to.

I can put the names into an array (2D) and access the individual members, but I need to be able to compare the list name in the array to the tab names to find the correct tab. Once found, copy ALL the contents of that tab to "Reps No Longer Here" (next available row).

When it is finished the sheet "Reps No Longer Here" should be a complete list of all of the tabs listed in the array and sorted by the rep name.

How the heck do I do this? I'm really having a problem comparing the tabs to the list array and then copying all of the non-empty rows to the "Reps No Longer Sheet"

I appreciate all the help...

Jeff

ADDED:

Here is what I have so far, but it just isn't working:

```
Private Sub Combinedata()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim DataRng As Range
Dim Rw As Long
Dim Cnt As Integer
Dim ar As Variant
Dim Last As Integer

Cnt = 1

Set ws = Worksheets("Total Tabs")
Set wsMain = Worksheets("Reps No Longer Here")

wsMain.Cells.Clear

ar = ws.Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Last = 1

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each ArrayElement In ar 'Check if worksheet name is found in array
            If ws.name <> wsMain.name Then
                If Cnt = 1 Then
                    Set DataRng = ws.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
                    DataRng.Copy wsMain.Cells(Cnt, 1)
                Else: Rw = wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'don't copy header rows
                DataRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(DataRng.Rows.Count - 1, _
                DataRng.Columns.Count).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(Rw, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Cnt = Cnt + 1

Last = Last + 1


Next ArrayElement
Next sh


End Sub
```

UPDATE - 7/3/14

This is the modified code. I'll highlight the line that is giving syntax error.

```
Sub CopyFrom2To1()

Dim Source As Range, Destination As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim arArray As Variant

Set Source = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:N1")
Set Dest = Worksheets("Reps No Longer Here").Range("A1:N1")

arArray = Sheets("Total Tabs").Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For i = 1 To 100


    For j = 1 To 100

        If Sheets(j).name = arArray(i, 1) Then        
                Source.Range("A" & j).Range("A" & j & ":N" & j).Copy ' A1:Z1 relative to A5 for e.g.
                ***Dest.Range("A" & i ":N" & i).Paste***
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Post what you've tried already.

Comment: I don't know what's up with the formatting. I do properly format code....

Comment: When writing your post, there's a button "{ }" that will format code properly. I've just edited your message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to a very similar problem was posted here yesterday by me. Have a look at the main loop in the code:

```
Sub CopyFrom2TO1()
Dim Source as Range, Destination as Range
Dim i as long, j as long

Set Source = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set Dest = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

for i = 1 to 100

    for j = 1 to 100
        if Dest.Cells(j,1) = Source.Cells(i,1) then
                Source.Range("A" & j).Range("A1:Z1").Copy ' A1:Z1 relative to A5 for e.g.
                Dest.Range("A"&i).Paste
                Exit For
        end if
    next j
next i
End Sub
```

This would need slight modifications for your purpose, but it essentially does the same thing. Compares a column to a another column and copies wherever a match takes places.

[Unable to find how to code: If Cell Value Equals Any of the Values in a Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518157/unable-to-find-how-to-code-if-cell-value-equals-any-of-the-values-in-a-range/24518502#24518502)

Comment: hnk - This is cool, however still a little confused. How would I use the array of list names to compare to sheet name?

Comment: you can cycle through sheets as Worksheets(1), (2), etc. and compare wSheet(j).Name = ArrayValue(i)

Comment: hnk - One more question, the line "Dest.Range("A"&i).Paste is throwing a syntax error. I'll also post my modified code for you to review, if you would, to make sure I'm on the right track.